# How do I enable editing JavaScript files while debugging in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, edit-and-continue

How do I enable editing JavaScript files while debugging in Visual Studio 2013
This works in VS2010 by simply disabling Edit and Continue.
This is useful as you can change the Javascript code then refresh the browser and the debugger remains connected improving development workflow.
Just does not seem to work with my new VS2013.

Comment: What doesn't work? What happens?

Comment: If is set a breakpoint in Javascript and then want to change some code, I can't. The file is read only. So i have to stop the debugger which requires restarting internet explorer. Its just cumbersome. I used to be able to make a change then save then refresh browser.

Comment: Seems to work for me. Make sure you are editing the source file and not the one loaded for debugging. I have seen it load another code panel at times for the attached process.

Comment: Looks like my AMD loader may be playing up. Maybe non-issue. Have [dynamic] on my .js files.